# Setting Routes Dynamically in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm brand new to Laravel, and I'm tinkering with it in different ways to understand how it works.

One of the first things that I've tried is to create routes dynamically by creating a routes config file that is essentially an array of views, and loop through them to create the route. It looks like this:

```html
// Loop through the routes
foreach( config("routes.web") as $route ){

  $GLOBALS["tmp_route"] = $route;

  // set the path for home
  $path = ($route == "home" ? '/' : $route);

  Route::get( $path, function() {
      return view($GLOBALS["tmp_route"]);
  });

// foreach
}
```

I know the loop is working fine, but what I get is `'Undefined index: tmp_route'`.

I'm confused as to why this isn't working? Any ideas? If I echo out the tmp_route it echos out the value, but fails at the return view(.

Comment: Why are you doing it this way? `$GLOBALS` in a Laravel install is making me twitch uncontrollably - it's a bad, bad code smell and totally unnecessary.

Comment: More than anything I'm trying to understand how to run Route::get in a loop for curiousity's sake. I'm open to suggestions. I started with Laravel about 2 hours ago.

Comment: I've never seen a problem that required a loop to build routes. Rather than have an array of routes in the config, you'd just put those routes right in the route file. For fully dynamic, arbitrary routes, the answer below is a good one, but in most cases you're going to be having routes like `file/1` or `foo/bar`.

Answer (score 2):

We don't use loops in routes usually. Actually, I've never used a loop in routes if I remember correctly. My suggestion is create a route with paramater and assign it to a controller method. e.g:

```
// Note that if you want a route like this, just with one parameter,
// put it to end of your other routes, otherwise it can catch other
// single hard-coded routes like Route::get('contact')
Route::get('{slug}')->uses('PageController@show')->name('pages.show');
```

Then in your PageController

```
public function show($slug) {

    $view = $slug == '/'?'home':$slug;
    return view($view);        

}
```

With this, *http://example.com/my-page* will render views/my-page.blade.php view. As you can see I also gave him a name, *pages.show*. You can use *route* helper to create links with this helper. e.g.

```
echo route('pages.show','about-us'); // http://example.com/about-us
echo route('pages.show','contact'); // http://example.com/contact
```

In blade templates:

```
<a href="{{ route('pages.show','about-us') }}">About Us</a>
```

Please look at the documentation for more and other cool stuff